# UItextView disable select option

Tags: ios

I have a UItextView created with the codes to which I have assigned some gestures. The UItextView should not be editable and I also wanted to remove the possibility to select the text by press and holding on it, including the menu cut/paste which shows up. all over internet I found:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
return NO;
}
```

I inserted this code in my file, and set the text.delegate = self. I even included UItextViewDelegate in the .h file
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the `editable` property of the `UITextView`.

To disabled copy paste, the easiest way would be to subclass the UITextView, and implement `canPerformAction:withSender:` like so:

```
@interface MyTextView : UITextView @end

@implementation MyTextView

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

If you are using a XIB or Storyboard to layout your UI, make sure to give the text view the correct class.

Comment: Well, you should add the code to a subclass of `UITextView`, not your view controller.

Comment: See another edit.
My example defines a new subclass of text view, which disables actions.

Comment: so when I create it I have to do instead of  textname = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: textframe];, this:  textname = [[theNewClass alloc] initWithFrame: textframe];

Comment: @LeoNatan, I agree a subclass is the better way to do it. **General Note**: while it might be tempting to creating a *category* on `UITextView` instead, **DON'T** do it. Categories affect all class instances in the project, whether or not your specific controller imports it. Hence, it more often than not would break something either immediately or later down the road (in some library, etc or your code perhaps)-- yeah, I learned the hard way. Good luck.

Comment: I tried doing this: textname = [[theNewClass alloc] initWithFrame: textframe]; and and creating a .h and .m files with the code above, but it doesn't have any effect. why?

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method and see if it stops there. If not, you are not using the correct class.

Comment: WORKS!! Now works, i used this code - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
but using @Leo Natan method, but still even if the test is not highlighted, the view scrolls down, af it the hilighting was invisible. How can I prevent this?